# Latex and gedit: color text in \footnote

Tags: editors, gedit

My question is linked with using Latex and gedit together. I am currently writing a large academic text and I am putting a lot of text into footnotes. Is there an easy way or a nice plugin that would change the **visuals of gedit** so that it changes the **color** of all the text within a `\footnote`-macro? I'd like to be better able to discern the proper text and the footnote text. Gedit is already color-coding all the macros, which is really nice.

So in short: **how to make gedit color everything within** `\footnote` macro? (i.e. how to make it change xxx in `\footnote{xxx}` to e.g. slightly blueish color)

Comment: I got this far: [Making GtkSourceview Language](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/NewLanguage).